# pdf.js viewer incorrectly storing image data

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

I have a function that is called when a button is clicked and loads a document from the servlet.  However, the way this is supposed to work is that it loads a multipage document and I have a next/previous button which I found off of the pdf.js website.

What is happening is that when I load a document and look through it, then click to open another document, when I am clicking next/previous, it still is going through the older document.

For example, I initially load a 2 page document into the viewer.  I can click next/previous and look through the pages of this document as normal.  I then click a button to view the next document, which is a 3 page document.  I can click next to view the 3 pages, but when I click previous, it will go back to the previous document that I had loaded in initially.

Here is the code:

```
function getDocument(){


var request = $.ajax({
            url: "IndexServlet",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                    token: "go",
                    fileName: $("#fileName").val(),
                    batchName: $("#folderName").val()
                  } 
             });

request.done(function( data ) {

var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(data);

    function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
      var base64 = dataURI;
      var raw = window.atob(base64);
      var rawLength = raw.length;
      var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

      for(var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return array;
    }


    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

    var pdfDoc = null,
        pageNum = 1,
        pageRendering = false,
        pageNumPending = null,
        scale = 1,
        canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    /**
     * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
     * @param num Page number.
     */
    function renderPage(num) {
      pageRendering = true;
      // Using promise to fetch the page
      pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

        // Wait for rendering to finish
        renderTask.promise.then(function () {
          pageRendering = false;
          if (pageNumPending !== null) {
            // New page rendering is pending
            renderPage(pageNumPending);
            pageNumPending = null;
          }
        });
      });

      // Update page counters
      document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
    }

    /**
     * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
     * finished. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
     */
    function queueRenderPage(num) {
      if (pageRendering) {
        pageNumPending = num;
      } else {
        renderPage(num);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Displays previous page.
     */
    function onPrevPage() {
      if (pageNum <= 1) {
        return;
      }
      pageNum--;
      queueRenderPage(pageNum);
    }
    document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

    /**
     * Displays next page.
     */
    function onNextPage() {
      if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
        return;
      }
      pageNum++;
      queueRenderPage(pageNum);
    }
    document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

    /**
     * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
     */
     PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
      pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
      document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

      // Initial/first page rendering
      renderPage(pageNum);
    });


});

}
```

Comment: Did you unbind document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage); listeners?

Comment: It seems like that is what is happening here, it's almost like the previous button "function" only works for the first iteration of the get document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge shoutout to async5 for the idea on this answer:

Switched my next and previous functions, heres the updated code:

```
function getDocument(){

$("#prev").unbind();
$("#next").unbind();

var pdfDoc = null,
    pageNum = 1,
    scale = 0.8,
    canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var request = $.ajax({
            url: "IndexServlet",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                    token: "go",
                    fileName: $("#fileName").val(),
                    batchName: $("#folderName").val()
                  } 
             });

 request.done(function( data ) {

 var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(data);


 PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
  document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;


  renderPage(pageNum);

function renderPage(num) {
  pageRendering = true;
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;


    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext);
  });


  document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
}


$("#prev").click(function(){
  if (pageNum > 1) {
   pageNum--;
   //queueRenderPage(pageNum);
   renderPage(pageNum);
  }

});

$("#next").click(function(){
  if (pageNum < pdfDoc.numPages) {
     pageNum++;
     //queueRenderPage(pageNum);
     renderPage(pageNum);

  }


  });
});
});


}



function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
var base64 = dataURI;
var raw = window.atob(base64);
var rawLength = raw.length;
var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

for(var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
 array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}
return array;
}
```